# Python/VB Script Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm new to Python/VB Script and am needing some help.  I have tried several different If/Then statements but can't seem to get it straight.  I am hoping for some help.  I have 3 fields.  ZONING, SQFeet_1, and Buildout. Depending on the Value of the ZONING field, will depend on what formula I need to use.  For instance, if ZONING = RS6 then I need to use the formula  (SQFeet_1/6000*.80) or if ZONING = SP then I need to use the formula (SQFeet_1/2000*.80), etc...  How would I write the IF/Then statement to get the results?  Or would I need to use a different statement?

[image]

Comment: If [ZONING] = 'RS6':
          Then (SQFeet_1/6000*.80)
Elif [ZONING] = 'SP':
          Then (SQFeet_1/2000*.80)

Comment: You should add that code to your question, users here like to see the effort you've put in so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best go is use of dictionary:

```
def getDivider(A,B):
    aDict={'RS6':6000,'SP':2000}
    if A in aDict:  return B/aDict[A]*0.8
    return -1
```

======================================

```
getDivider(!ZONING!,!SQFeet_1!)
```

Update following @Paul suggestion:

```
def getDivider(A,B):
  aDict={'RS6':6000,'SP':2000}
  return B/aDict.get(A,0)*0.8
```

Comment: why should the function return -1?

Comment: To answer this read line above

Comment: A different approach would be `return B/aDict.get(A, 0)*0.8` where 0 is a value you want returned when a value can't be found in the dict (aka, the default value). No need to check if the key is present.

Comment: @Paul very nice, will make it even shorter

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to try this out today and will get back with ya'll!